# Grouping a set of revolving years (Reporting Services 2016)

Tags: sql, reporting-services, sql-server-2016, reportbuilder3.0, ssrs-2016

Long time Stackoverflow user, but never actually asked questions. I'm currently stumped on a report request.

What I need to do with Report Builder is displaying data on pages grouped by three years, but here's the catch: I need it to be revolving.

I put together a query, but it's static:

```
SELECT distinct *, (dense_rank() over (order by [Year]) - 1) / 3 + 1 as [group]
FROM dwmy
```

It works fine for grouping years when I don't also need to still display past years. To give you an idea of what I'm trying to accomplish.

So, in the current year, it would look like:

[image: 2019, 2020, 2021]

In 2022:

[image: 2020, 2021, 2022]

In 2023:

[image: 2021, 2022, 2023]

As you can see, the current year still stays within the first group, but as a new year starts, it slowly works its way off the first page. The old groupings would still be on older pages, so users could still see the old groupings of 2019, 2020, 2021 or 2020, 2021, 2022.

[image: 2019, 2020, 2021]
[image: 2020, 2021, 2022]
[image: 2021, 2022, 2023]

Comment: If you want to change the names of the columns, you'll need to use dynamic SQL.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what the report will look like. Will it only ever show three years, or will it show three year as the '2021 view of the data' and then on the next page three years from the '2020 view of the data' etc? Could you supply some sample data and the expected out from that same data.

Comment: I think you're overthinking this. `SELECT *, (YEAR(GETDATE()) - [YEAR]) / 3 + 1...`

Comment: Hey @AlanSchofield. I've attached Excel data to show what exactly I'm trying to accomplish. It needs to be a rolling list of instructors for the 3 consecutive years. I thought maybe inserting duplicates for each group may be the easiest way of accomplishing this, but if there's an easier way of display the same data across pages, I'd love to hear it. Thank you.